# Generics without new()

Tags: c#, generics

I have a dozen methods in my project (C# 2.0) that look like this:

```
internal bool ValidateHotelStayEntity(DataRow row)
{
    return (new HotelStayEntity(row)).Validate();
}
```

... but for different 'entity' classes.  (Okay, not quite that trivial, I've simplified the code here.)

It looks like a good candidate for generics and I came up with this:

```
internal bool ValidateEntity<T>(DataRow row) where T : EntityBase
{
    return (new T(row)).Validate();
}
```

And of course I get the "Cannot create an instance of the type parametrer 'T' because it does not have the new() constraint" error.

The problem is that these 'entity' classes do not have a public parameterless constructor, nor a way of adding the 'row' data in afterwards.  And as EntityBase is part of the company framework I have no control over it (ie I can't change it).

Is there any way around this?

Comment: I don't have time for an example now, but you can create a generic factory method that can be passed the row.

Comment: Why are you passing around DataRows instead of your Entities?  Shouldn't the Entities have been validated well before they're treated as DataRows?

Comment: They weren't really DataRows, they were DataRow-like obkects that I 'simplified' for this post.  I didn't want to get sidetracked with explaining the imposed framework I have to deal with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yet another way could be to involve reflection at the price of compile time checking and decreased performance:

```
internal bool ValidateEntity<T>(DataRow row)
{ 
   object entity = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { row });
   MethodInfo validate = typeof(T).GetMethod("Validate");
   return (bool) validate.Invoke(entity, new object[]);
}
```

Note that this would work even if the entities do not have a common ancestor

Comment: If Validate() will throw exception it will be wrapped to the TargetInvocationException, I do not think this good. Casting to EntityBase seems to be much more preferable.

Comment: You can cache that MethodInfo in a static variable (because it's generic it would be per closed type). Now you remove the need to reflect it for every call.

Comment: @MikeBrown Yes you can but you will have to maintain a Type to MethodInfo dictionary (the classes might not have a common ancestor)

Comment: Ah yes I see. This is a generic function. I was thinking it might be a generic validation helper class. If the class was closed over T, you could use the static variable. But you're right it won't work for a single generic method.

Answer (score 15):

One simple way is to provide a factory function:

```
internal bool ValidateEntity<T>(DataRow row, Func<DataRow, T> factory)
    where T : EntityBase
{
    return factory(row).Validate();
}
```

and call with:

```
bool valid = ValidateEntity(row, x => new Foo(x));
```

Mind you, at that point it's more complicated than just calling

```
bool valid = new Foo(row).Validate()
```

in the first place...

It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve in your real context, but this sort of factory/provider approach can certainly be useful at other times. Note that calling a factory delegate can also be *considerably* faster than using `new T()` with a constraint, [as I blogged a while ago](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/08/22/optimization-and-generics-part-1-the-new-constraint.aspx). Irrevelant in many cases, but worth knowing about.

EDIT: For .NET 2.0 compatibility you'd need to declare the delegate yourself, but that's easy:

```
public delegate TResult Func<T, TResult>(T input);
```

If you're *really* using C# 2 (rather than, say, C# 3 targeting .NET 2.0) then you won't be able to use lambda expressions either, but you can still use anonymous methods:

```
bool valid = ValidateEntity(row, delegate(DataRow x) { return new Foo(x); });
```

Comment: I don't think there is a Func in 2.0.

Comment: @PeterTrevor: Oops, hadn'y noticed the .NET 2.0 requirement - but you can easily define your own delegates. Will edit to give an example of that.

Comment: @Shibumi Definitely, I'm surprised the OP chose my answer but I guess he just wanted something that fitted his current method signature

Comment: Thanks everyone.  @Jon: For this case it really is C#2 (VS2005) ... not MY choice.  But I've filed away all these suggestions for later use, this kind of problem is bound to come up again on a different project (one that uses VS2010).

Comment: @PeterTrevor: But as I said in my edit, you don't need C# 3 for this to work. It makes it neater to use lambda expressions, but that's all. I still question whether this is necessary at all though...

Answer (score 1):

An example of @JohnSaunders' factory method solution:

```
internal bool ValidateEntity<T>(DataRow row, Func<DataRow, T> factory) where T : EntityBase
{
    return (factory(row)).Validate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
internal bool ValidateEntity<T>(DataRow row) where T : EntityBase 
{
     return ((T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { row })).Validate(); 
}
```